# Helper function within a main function

Tags: python

I have a main function, and helper functions inside the main function that will retrieve values from an excel spreadsheet

Ex.

```
import openpyxl
def main():
 dict = {}
 dname = 'Animal list'
 animal = {}
 while opt in ['0', '1']:
  if opt == '0':
    print('goodbye')
  if opt == '1':
    file_open(dname, dict, animal)
 return


def file_open(dname, dict, animal):
 open_excel(dname) 
 create_animal_dict(data, dict)


def open_excel(default_name):
    filename = dname
    try:
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
    except:
        print("No file")
        return
    sheet = workbook.active
    columns = sheet.max_column
    rows= str(sheet.max_row)
    max_column_letter = chr(ord("A")+ number_of_columns -1 )
    raw= sheet['A1': max_column_letter+number_of_rows]
    data= []
    for row in raw:
        sublist = []
        for cell in raw:
            sublist.append(cell.value)
        data.append(sublist)
    return(data) #creates a list of list
```

The error i get is "builtins.NameError: name 'data' is not defined"

Im having trouble, taking 'data' from open_file(dname) and having it being a parameter for create_animal_dict, I was wondering how to to bring a variable from one helper function to another.

Thanks for any help or tips!

Comment: (1) The helper functions don't seem to be **inside** the main function but after it. (2) Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: @MichaelButscher In the main function its shown under "If opt == '1'", it's calling another function called open_file(), and then that's calling another function  open_excel(), however, I did label one of the functions wrong, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

You are not receiving the output from your `open_excel` function, which then I assume needs to be passed to the `create_animal_dict` function, e.g.

```
def file_open(dname, dict, animal):
 data = open_excel(dname) 
 create_animal_dict(mainlist, dict, data)
```

I assume the error is coming from you calling `data` from inside `create_animal_dict`, which this would solve.

But you should also take the output from `create_animal_dict` and pass it back to `main` function if you are structuring your program this way.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's my problem. I just don't know how to go about it

Comment: The above will solve your original `'data' is not defined` problem. As for how you want the information to flow, it is not apparent from your snippet what end result you are looking for. I would suggest have the return from your `file_open` function collected in your `main`.

Comment: I didn't see that issue with the mismatching variables, but it still seems to not work even with the same variable